# Fog S3 Upload leads to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am developing a platform that allows merchants to upload a picture of their store. I am using Carrierwave+fog for this. As the app is hosted on heroku, the pictures will need to be stored on amazon s3.

On my local machine, everything works fine if the storage is local, but things go wrong once fog handles the uploading.

I will first post the local storage version (works fine), then my current fog-enabled s3 version together with the error that I am getting.

Local storage version (works fine):

```
# app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Fog-enabled s3 version (doesn't work):

```
# app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end

# config/initializers/fog.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxxx',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'xxxx'       # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'yyyy'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = true                          # optional, defaults to true
end
```

When I now create or edit a new store, the picture is actually successfully uploaded to s3, but rails gives an Permission denied error message (app/tmp/carrierwave/20121104-0929-5512-8270/04.png could not be accessed).

Full Error Message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `unlink'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1406:in `block in remove_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1414:in `platform_support'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1405:in `remove_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:785:in `remove_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:563:in `block in rm'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:562:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:562:in `rm'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:217:in `delete'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:60:in `block in store!'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/uploader/store.rb:58:in `store!'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:347:in `store!'
carrierwave (0.5.8) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:217:in `store_bild!'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:401:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:37:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:163:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:161:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:62:in `block in update'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/stores_controller.rb:61:in `update'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__16358980__process_action__192134115__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:326:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:455:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

This error confuses me, as typing in app/tmp/carrierwave/20121104-0929-5512-8270/04.png directly into the browser works fine.

For completeness sake, here is the controller & model (same in both versions)

```
#stores_controller.rb
def create
  @store = Store.new(params[:store])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @store.save
      format.html { redirect_to @store, notice: 'Store was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @store, status: :created, location: @store }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @store.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

#models/store.rb
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :bild, PictureUploader
end
```

Comment: You could use [Carrierwave Direct](http://www.knight.io/repos/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) to upload the pictures directly from the browser to S3. You might otherwise run into issues if picture uploading takes a longer time than Heroku allows requests to run without sending a response. It should solve your problem too, though in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cache_dir to your uploader:

```
  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Also, you might have to add config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    # hack fix for windows machine due to tmp file permission error
    # per https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/220/
    if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'production'
      config.delete_tmp_file_after_storage = false  
    end
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['MF_S3_KEY'],       # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['MF_S3_SECRET'],       # required
      :region                 => 'us-east-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory  = ENV['MF_FLYER_BUCKET']                     # required
    #config.fog_host       = 'https://assets.example.com'            # optional, defaults to nil
    #config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
    #config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
```